# Some questions about the stat command for file systems

Tags: osx, hfs+

First of all, I'm completely ignorant regarding shell commands. So, please, be patient. Also, I'm using OS X, but I'm happy with an answer in the generality of Unix if such thing is possible.

I'm trying to execute the command `stat -f [some parameters here] [volume name]`.

According to references elsewhere, the most simple command of this form `stat -f /dev/disk0s2` is syntactically correct. However I've got the following:

```
 stat -f /dev/disk0s2
 /dev/disk0s2
```

According to here (https://www.computerhope.com/unix/stat.htm), for instance, I should get a paragraph full of information. In my case, I'm mostly interested in the block size obtained through the stat command.

Also, here (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42509/how-to-get-hfs-filesystem-blocksize), it's mentioned the parameters "%k, %z, %b". However in the manual of stat (i.e., by using `man stat`) I can't find such parameters. Furthermore I have no idea why the quotation marks are being used there (I've seen both `stat -f %k` and `stat -f "%k"`, for instance).

So, in summary, I have three questions:

1) Why `stat -f /dev/disk0s2` is not giving me the expected output?

2) What are these %k, %z and %b parameters and are they being mentioned in the manual?

3) What's the meaning of the quotation marks around the above mentioned parameters (for instance, `stat -f %k` and `stat -f "%k"`)? Is this a general stuff in the syntax of Unix commands?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line tools that come pre-installed on OS X come from FreeBSD, but many guides online will probably assume a Linux environment and GNU tools. They're not always the same.

Compare the two man pages for [FreeBSD stat](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stat&sektion=1&manpath=freebsd-release-ports) and [GNU stat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html). In FreeBSD, `-f` sets the output format and takes a corresponding argument. In GNU stat `-f` asks for the output about the filesystem (not the named file), and takes no argument.

So, 1) the result is different because you're using a different tool, 2) the format options are mentioned under "Formats" in the FreeBSD man page. 3) The quotes aren't really related to `stat` itself, but the shell. Command line arguments that contain characters special to the shell (like whitespace, or glob characters `?*[]` etc) need to be quoted to prevent the *shell* from processing them. But `%` isn't special (at least not in that context), so it doesn't matter if it's quoted or not.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. About 3, is there an example where the shell would read it differently with and without the quotation marks?

Comment: Ah, ok. I haven't refreshed the page to see your edited answer. Still I can't understand the quotation marks well. It looks like it only makes sense when I'm adding special characters to names of things, but this %k, for instance, plays apparently the role of a sub option so even if % was special, wouldn't I want it to be processed?

Comment: Try `ls "*"` v.s. `ls *`

Comment: @xenoid Yes, I've got it in this case. But in the above example the % in %k seems to be something like an option (or an option inside an option) and not a name pointing to something, so it looks like I actually would want the shell to process it as %k and not "%k" even if % was a special character.

Comment: Out of habit perhaps? Very often you use the format to print several things with spaces in between: `stat -c "%8s %n" *` and the quotes are necessary then. Note in passing that you can have length specifiers in the format, or that you can make arbitrary strings: `stat -c "File %n is %s bytes" *`.

Comment: @user40276, In this case you don't want the shell to process anything, you want to give the `-f` (or `-c`) and the `%k` as arguments to `stat`. Which you get with either `%k`, or `"%k"`, all that the shell processes there is to remove the quotes. With globs the quotes make a further difference, but since `%` doesn't do anything, it doesn't matter. And you could as well quote every word if you like: `"stat" "-f" "%k" "foo"` works just fine. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CommandsAndArguments and go from there.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what " actually performs in the shell. For instance, I may have a file named %s and type `stat -c "File %n is named %s"`, however I will get the wrong output as % will be processed in %s.

Comment: @user40276, `stat foo bar` is a call to `stat` with two distinct arguments. The splits the command line to distinct arguments on the spaces. (The command doesn't see the space that separates the arguments, it sees two distinct strings.) `stat "foo bar"` is a call to `stat` with one argument that just so happens to contain a space. Here, the quotes prevent the splitting and make the space go literally to the command. You can substitute a `%` sign there, it works just like any letter in this case.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm still confused. What would have to be corrected in `stat -c "File %n is named %s"` (a variation of @xenoid example above) if I want to print `File %s is named %s` instead of `File %s is named 12` (where I have a file named %s with 12 bytes). Unfortunately, I can't test it since `stat -c` apparently not valid in OS X.

Comment: `%n` is replaced by the file name, and `%s` by the file size. Not to be confused with the `%s` you see in C/Java/Python that tells that the parameter is a string. In other words, in C/JAva/Python, `%X` is a format **type**, and in `stat` format `%X` indicates a **value**.

Comment: @xenoid Yes, I've already got it, but if I have a file named %s how can I refer to its name without interpreting it as a value? That's what I was trying to ask. At first, I thought that enclosing it by quotation marks would do the work, but it doesn't.

Comment: @user40276, `echo 12345678901 > %s` and then `stat -f "File %N has size %z" %s` (on Mac). `echo 12345678901 > %s` and `stat -c "File %n has size %s" %s` (on Linux). The quoted string is one argument, `%s` is another. `-f`/`-c` takes the next argument in order as the format string, the rest are file names. If you don't specify that option, then there's no format string and everything is taken as filenames (assuming no other options). So `stat %s` would run `stat` on the file `%s`. In any case, the meaning of `%s` is specific to `stat`, _not to the shell_.

Comment: Sorry for insisting again. Suppose that I have a file named %s with 12 bytes. I want to print `File %s is named %s` by correcting the command `stat -f "File %n is named %s"`, which prints `File %s is named 12`. In other words, I want the %s in the command to be read in the same way as for instance the word `File` or `named` are being read. How can I do it? That's what I thought that the quotation marks would do, but it doesn't as everyone already have said.

Comment: @user40276, if you want a literal percent sign in the output, use `%%`. It's the usual way for escaping `%` in tools that take format specifiers of the `%x` type (and it comes from C and `printf`). It's mentioned in the FreeBSD man page, but I can't see it on the GNU one (it might be mentioned in the full manual).